# Может ли процессор Intel Pentium B980 считать в три раза медленнее, чем intel core i5-4690T?

Tags: архитектура, производительность

Мы с моей студенткой решаем вычислительную задачу методом конечных элементов. Мы берём некоторые входные данные, а компьютер их считает, уравнение за уравнением.
Большая часть инструкций (не менее 80%) выполняется последовательно, то есть параллелизма там практически нет. Графический процессор (GPU) там не используется.

У меня компьютер **`intel Core i5-4690T CPU 2.5 ГГц`**, **`8 гб`** оперативной памяти. 
У моей студентки **`intel Pentium CPU B980`**, **`2.4 ГГц`** оперативной памяти. 
У нас обоих 64 разрядная ОС.

У меня общий индекс производительности windows **`5,9`**. У неё - **`4,4`**. В частности по процессору оценка, операций вычисления в секунду **`7,5`** у меня и **`5,8`** у неё.

В процессе расчёта на обоих компах загрузка примерно 0,9-1,5 гб оперативной памяти, 50-90% ЦП, эти показатели колеблются в обоих случаях.

По моей экспертной оценке, раз оперативной памяти в обоих случаях хватает, а программа выполняется в целом последовательно, время расчёта должно отличаться не более чем на 50%, так как расчёты делает АЛУ. На деле, на первом компьютере программа считает за **2 минуты**, на втором тот же расчёт- за **7,5 минут.** Более 3,5 раз разрыв!

Я погасил на втором компьютере все левые процессы и вирусов не нашёл.

Коллега говорит что всё дело в архитектуре, виноват слабенький, упрощенный и устаревший процессор второго компа.

**Вопрос:**  действительно ли вышеуказанных архитектурных различий достаточно, чтобы расчёт тянулся в три с половиной раза дольше?

Comment: Операционка и другие программы же всё равно жрут процессорное время, просто на i5 больше потоков, поэтому другие проги меньше на них влияют. Но вообще там же много чего влияет, задержка и частота оперативки, количество кэш памяти + i5 ещё разгоняется до 3.5Ггц, очень много факторов в общем.

Comment: Заходите на любой сайт сравнения CPU, смотрите там сравнительную производительность, [например](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Pentium-B980-vs-Intel-Core-i5-4690T) - Around 3.2x better. Учитывая, что у него в 3 раза больше кэша, это не удивительно

Comment: а что и как Вы там считаете?

Comment: Разница в производительности может быть и в десятки раз. Зависит от размера кеша, длины конвейера, предсказателя переходов, набора команд...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ мы считаем поле, распределение носителей и так далее в фотодиоде методом конечных элементов. Задаём граничные условия, материал и компьютер сам считает.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin а какие типы и структуры данных?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ с плавающей запятой в основном. Массивы. Точных деталей реализации не знаю.

Comment: Производительность это сильно нелинейная функция от параметров системы. Кеш сильно влияет на скорость, если программа вся попадает в кеш, то скорость резко увеличивается. А если в кеш попадают еще и данные, то совсем хорошо становится. А если вдруг все выгрузилось в своп, то все становится очень печально и медленно.